# How to enable click-sorting for views table display based on Search API index?

Tags: views, 8, search

I'm trying to create a view with table display based on Search API (database search) index, with column-sorting (column set as `Sortable` in the display settings). However, this option isn't available for my view fields, no matter if they are based on `string` or `fulltext` Search API fields. Is there anything I can do to enable this?

I'm using latest Drupal 8.7.x nad Search API 1.12

Edit:

It seems that availability of click-sorting is determined in `\Drupal\search_api\Plugin\views\field\SearchApiFieldTrait::clickSortable` method. The check inside that fails, because field definition array doesn't contain a `search_api field` key. So is there anything I can do to add it there?

BTW. th support for click-sorting was added in https://www.drupal.org/project/search_api/issues/2816979. There are some SOLR-related issues mentioned, but noting related to my use-case.

Comment: Do you have indexes created on those fields?

Comment: Yes, otherwise these fields wouldn't be available to the view, AFAIK.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it turned out, it was my stupid mistake - search index field can be added to views (as a views field) in 2 ways, with one of them having (Indexed field) appended to the field label.

**When I added field with (Indexed field) appended, I can set that field a Sortable**.